# WebDriver: How to deal with parallel test execution using the same browser (Firefox)?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

WebDriver: How to deal with parallel test execution using the same browser (Firefox)?

1. i need to execute many tests and many instances of the same browser however im having problems with cookies because the browsers are sharing the cookies used.
2. Possible to resolve the issue using browser / firefox profiles?

thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

1. Delete cookies before every test using `driver().manage().deleteAllCookies()`
2. Create new webdriver instance for every test
3. When running in parallel use forks instead of threads, refer to this article for more details: http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/fork-options-and-parallel-execution.html - also you're able to use forks in testNG

Comment: thanks so much for the help, what is the best process for running mutiple builds in jenkins if they have to then share the same browser? I see that many people use GitHub etc to trigger there builds within jenkins are you familar with this?

Comment: This is correct answer. WebDriver is not thread safe, you would need to create new WebDriver instance, i.e. browser for each test. If you do so, they will be independent profiles and cookies will not be shared.